# layout_weight working in simulator, not on device

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout with two listviews, a text view, and another linear layout to hold some buttons.  I want the second listview to be twice the height of the first.  I have set the height of both list views to 0dp and gave the first a layout_weight of 1 and the second a weight of 2, and then set the weightSum of the containing view to 3.  Here is the actual layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/categoryList" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/itemList" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/walletStr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buyBtn"
            android:text="buy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

On the simulator, this produces the desired effect, but on the actual device almost all of the space goes to the top listview.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `weightSum` attribute on the outer `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

linear layout not have only 2 list, also have more component and you have to consider.
The weightSum should be divided all component of this linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="7"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/categoryList" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/itemList" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/walletStr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buyBtn"
            android:text="buy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```